# How to send data from router to express handlebar template

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, handlebars.js, router

I'm having a hard time trying to get data retrieved from a postgres DB via router into a handlebar template.

This is the folder structure:

```
-node_modules
-public
-routes
--api
---db.js
-views
--layouts
---main.handlebars
--index.handlebars
-index.js
```

Here is an example request in the db.js file:

```
//get all users
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  db.result("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id")
    .then(data => {
      res.json(data.rows);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return console.log("error");
    });
});
```

And I want this data to be displayed into a template.

This is the index.js file:

```
const users = require('./routes/api/db')

const app = express();

//init middleware
app.use(logger);

//handle bars middle
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// body parser
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));

//render
// app.get('/', users.getAllUsers);

app.get('/displaydata', (req,res)=> {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'DATA',

/* HOW DO I GET THE DATA TO BE DISPLAYED OVER HERE?*/

    });
});

//members api routes
app.use('/api/db', users);
```

Comment: have you got solutions?

Comment: This didnt work, unfortunately. When I go the root page (localhost:5000/) I want to render the template but I also want that route to be called and to load that data on the page.

Comment: i didn't  get proparely what your saying, i have just itrate what i understood, /dispalydata means load index.hbars without tempate and /index means template with other pages your saying...

Answer (score 0):

You have to change below i guess,..

// db.js need to changes like below

```
//get all users
// router.get("/", (req, res) => {
module.exports.getUsers = function (reqParams) {
  return new Proimise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.result("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id")
      .then(data => resolve(status : true, data: data.rows));
      .catch(error =>reject({status : false, data: error}));
  })
};
// });
```

// index.js need to changes like below

```
const users = require(`/db`);

app.get('/displaydata', async(req, res)=> {
  const reslt = await users.getUsers(req);
  res.render('index', {
      title: 'DATA',
      data: reslt.status ? reslt.data : []
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I figured this out. I'm still learning express so I'm not sure if this is the cleanest way.

I didnt end up making any changes to index.js, just to the route by rendering inside of it:

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
let dbData;
db.result("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id asc")
    .then(data => {
        dbData = data.rows;
        res.render('membersView', {
            title: 'Users',
            dbData
        })
    })
    .catch(error => {
        return console.log("error");
    });
});
```

Then I was able to display it in the handlebars template:

```
<h2 class="mt-5 mb-5 text-center" id="ok">{{ title }}</h2>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Active</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each dbData }}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{ id }}</th>
      <td>{{ name }}</td>
      <td>{{ email }}</td>
      <td>{{ active }}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```